# Algorithm to return all possible paths in this program to a nested list

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, loops, depth-first-search

So I have a game with a function `findViableMoves(base)`. If i call this function at the start with the parameter `base`, I get an output `[move1, move2 ... moven]` which denotes all of the n viable moves that the user can perform give the state `base`. (there are in fact 2 root moves)

Upon performing a move, say `move2` - base gets changed depending on the move, the function gets called again and now we have an output for findViableMoves(base) of `[move21,move22 .... move2n].`

[Depth-first-tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbcS2.png)

If you look at this diagram, it's a very similar situation - there's no looping back, it's just a normal tree. I need a program that performs a depth-first search (i think?) on all the possible moves given a starting state of `base`, and then returns then in a list as such:

```
[[move1,move11,move111],[move1,move11,move112],....[moven,moven1,moven11],...]
```

There will be more elements in these lists (14 at most), but I was just wondering if someone could provide any hints over how I can build an algorithm to do this? Efficiency doesn't really matter to me as there isn't too many paths, I just want it done for now.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Comment: Pretty much seems to be a depth first search.actually! I will update nonetheless but will also give that a read. Thanks and sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you're after, but if you have a list or similar iterable that is changing while the loop is happening you could try something like the below.

This example allows the list and the loop condition to both remain dynamic during the loop execution.

```
import random
import sys
import time

changing_list = ['A', 27, 0.12]

def perform_operation(changing_list, counter):
    sometimes_add_another_element_threshold = 0.6
    if random.random() > sometimes_add_another_element_threshold:
        changing_list.append(random.random())
    print(changing_list[counter])

def main(z=0):
    safety_limit = 100
    counter = 0
    condition = True
    while condition and counter < safety_limit:
        perform_operation(changing_list, counter)
        counter += 1
        condition = counter<len(changing_list)

    print("loop finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    main(int(sys.argv[1])) if len(sys.argv)>1 else main()
    print(time.time() - start_time)
```

which provides output of varying length that looks something like:

```
A
27
0.12
0.21045788812161237
0.20230442292518247
loop finished
0.0058634281158447266
```

Comment: It's not exactly like that, I need an algorithm that scans all possible nodes - so for instance it could output [A,27,0.12,0.21....] and [A,27,0.12,0.202.....] depending on if those two lists satisfy a condition. I'm not very good at explaining it as I only started coding 2 weeks ago, but this diagram indicates what I'm looking for: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Depth-first-tree.svg/300px-Depth-first-tree.svg.png

Thanks a lot anyways, I really appreciate the help :)